# Thousands of page views but none are unique

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, page-views

I have a page that is getting thousands of page views, but very few are unique. Looking more closely, the ones that are not unique have the 'Previous page path' as itself. The page does not link to itself and there are no redirects to or from the page... any ideas what it could be?[image: google analytcis snapshot]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like bot traffic or possibly even a denial of service attack in progress.

You might want to block the IP address of the traffic source.